Would it be a good idea for Stack Overflow to have Stack Overflow Fridays?
Recently on Stack Overflow's official Twitter account, there was a tweet:

What's on every developer's dream holiday wish list? ✨ Stack Overflow Fridays to spend dedicated time giving back to the global developer community!
What would you do to help out your fellow devs? Read @CIOonline 's full developer wish list:

referring to an article on CIO.com:


Stack Overflow Fridays
Every Friday, the hectic developer life pauses for a moment and turns into a day of wisdom and community. Stack Overflow Fridays are
the perfect time to put aside your own projects and focus entirely on
helping the global developer community.
On this day, developers not only answer questions but also show their extensive knowledge and willingness to help others. The best
answers are not only celebrated but the developer is awarded the title
of “Hero of the Day” at the next meeting — a title that shows that
true greatness lies in sharing knowledge.



I'm aware that there's a community-a-thon running periodically, but considering that whomever runs the Twitter account seems enthusiastic about it, it feels like spending part of a workday, or a workday on the network sites of one's choice, and focus on helping the community feels like a wonderful idea to build bridges and perhaps kindle, or rekindle someone's interest in the network.
That someone in the company thinks its a great idea is wonderful - can we have this considered?  It seems that if this was broadly done across many orgs, it might help with concerns over user numbers, but where better to start than Stack Overflow?
